# Software & Updates does not show keys in Trusted software providers list

Tags: gnome

When I open Software & Updates (software-properties-gtk) the list of Trusted software providers in the Authentication tab is empty.

I use Ubuntu 22.04. But I also had this problem with 21.10. Probably with 21.04 as well. I don't remember exactly when it stopped working.

When I make `sudo apt-key list` I can see the list of keys.